# "missing item" in article mode using automatic uncover [beamer]

Tags: beamer, beamerarticle

I tried to use the automatic uncover option (beamer user guide, section 23.1) as follows:

% file test.tex

```
\begin{document}

This is a test.
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item First
\item Second
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

% file test.beamer.tex to produce the actual presentation; works as expected.

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer} 
\input{test.tex}
```

% file test.article.tex

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\setjobnamebeamerversion{test8.beamer}
\input{test8.tex}
\end{document}
```

which gives the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.6      \item F
               irst
```

The actual presentation has a lot of lists of items, making the automatic uncovering most desirable.  Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is 'works for me' (it should do: I fixed the bug!). Which version of `beamer` do you have?

Comment: @Joseph-Wright This is from the TeXLive2011 distribution... The most recent entry in the ChangeLog reads:  changeset:   441:208bcd589060
tag:         tip
user:        Vedran Miletiƒá <rivanvx@gmail.com>
date:        Mon Jul 12 19:35:36 2010 +0200

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at the docs... from the beamer.cls file, I find this:  \ProvidesClassRCS $Header: /home/vedranm/bitbucket/beamer/base/beamer.cls,v a6b1a8434d30 2010/06/21 09:34:49 rivanvx $

Comment: What I could do with is the version according to the documentation. Try `texdoc beamer`: the first page should have a line reading 'User Guide for version 3. _x_ ', where the _x_ is what is what I'm after.

Comment: Guide for version 3.10

Comment: Ah, that would be it then. The current release is 3.12, and this bug is fixed there. (I suspect it was fixed in 3.11 too). I'd recommend updating your `beamer`: `tlmgr update beamer` at the command line

Comment: @JosephWright That worked! Could you please write down this as an answer so that I can mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug which existed in `beamer` up to version 3.10. It is fixed in the current release (3.12), which for TeX Live can be installed using

```
tlmgr update beamer
```

at the command line. You may need `sudo`/Administrator privileges depending on how TeX Live was installed.

Answer (score 1):

Specifying a default overlay specification for `itemize` doesn't work with `beamerarticle` here, however it compiles both in presentation and in article mode if you specify it to `\item` in your `test.tex` file which you input:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item<+-> First
\item<+-> Second
\end{itemize}
```

It seems to be a bug, see [comp.text.tex](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/c8a94da4dd255126), so you could check if it's fixed in a newer `beamer` version and you don't need this workaround if you update.